# GA4 - Bigquery: How to get events by removing duplication based on user_pseudo_id?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have a landing page and a button download. We added a firebase tag to know when a user clicks on the button.

In Google Analytics, we have two data, one `Event count` counting each time the button is clicked and the second `Total Users`.
The Total Users is `The total number of unique users who have logged an event.`

So in our case (image below), 737 is the correct data to track. All these data are sent in Biquery but we are not able to find the `Total Users` info even to calculate.

[image]

In big query I started by this request

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT EXTRACT (WEEK from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as week_of_year,
   EXTRACT (YEAR from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as year,
   count(event_name) as nb_download,
   FROM `XXXXXXXXX.analytics_XXXXXXX.events_*` WHERE event_name = 'landing_event_download_apk'  GROUP BY event_date
```

I got the result `1,030` which is the `Event count`.

I don't really know how to get `Total users`.

I replaced `event_name` by `user_pseudo_id`  in the request but I got `671` instead of `737`

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT (WEEK from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as week_of_year,
       EXTRACT (YEAR from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as year,
       count(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) as nb_download,
       FROM `XXXXXXXXX.analytics_XXXXXXX.events_*` WHERE event_name = 'landing_event_download_apk'  GROUP BY event_date
```

Please how could I do ? Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Have you implemented User Id in your GA implementation? Also, have you enabled Google Signals in your GA property?

Comment: Hello @MinhazKazi we did not enable Google Signals and even User Id....these users comes from our landing page, so i don't know how we can give them an id. How to enable Google Signals ?

Comment: Can you confirm that your reporting identity is set to "Device Based"? Ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10976610?hl=en

Enabling Google Signals would actually create difference between the UI and BigQuery export (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9445345).

Comment: @MinhazKazi ok, I just activate the Google Signals by following the link.  But if Signals creates difference, how this could help me to have exact value as what we have in Firebase ? I'm now totally confused.

Comment: Activating Signals will only add to the difference. Sorry I might have miscommunicated - I was trying to make sure you did not have it turned on.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Now it is activated. Thanks a lot...I will see the difference is weeks coming.